# method 'fileopenex' of object '_MSProject' failed when automating MS Project from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I have an excel Macro which is supposed to open up MS Project and make a change to some custom fields and then close it again. Excel and Project are both version 2010, and the project is stored on MS Project Server 2010.

When I open MS Project manually and then detect it with VBA, everything works. But when I use VBA to open a new instance of Project (because I haven't manually opened MS Project), it throws an error:

[image]

Here are the two versions of the code:

```
Sub open_project_with_error()

    Dim projapp As MSProject.Application, prj As Project
    Set projapp = New MSProject.Application
    projapp.FileOpenEx Name:="<>\Name of my project", ReadOnly:=False
    Set prj = Projects("Name of my project")
  ' Do more things...
End Sub

Sub open_project_without_error()

    ' Manually open MS Project application before running this VBA
    Dim projapp As MSProject.Application, prj As Project
    Set projapp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    projapp.FileOpenEx Name:="<>\Name of my project", ReadOnly:=False
    Set prj = Projects("Name of my project")
  ' Do more things...
End Sub
```

Naturally, I expected that the problem was with the statement `New MSProject.Application`. However, this sub works perfectly, as expected:

```
Sub open_project_and_display_about()

    Dim projapp As MSProject.Application, prj As Project
    Set projapp = New MSProject.Application
    Debug.Print projapp.About()

End Sub
```

Which means that the error is only triggered by the combination of `New MSProject.Application` and `New MSProject.Application`.

Any way to resolve it?

Comment: Does this happen with every project server file? How about with .mpp files saved locally?

Comment: @RachelHettinger yes all server files. No, local .mpp files are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to try:

1. Set `projapp.Visible = True` to help debug issues.
2. [CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/createobject-function) **opens and returns** a reference to an object, so use it instead of manually opening Project and then using [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getobject-function) which just returns a reference to an already-opened object.
3. Qualify references to MSProject objects, e.g. `Dim prj as MSProject.Project` and `Set prj = projapp.Projects(....`

FWIW I am not able to replicate this issue with project pro 2013 opening files from project server.

Comment: Regarding 1, I saw no change adding that line.

Comment: I rewrote the code to use CreateObject instead of New, and got the same error.

Comment: I made the change you mentioned in (3) to qualify references, with no change.

Comment: Unless there is a pop-up box when you open Project manually (e.g. selecting a Profile) the only difference between using CreateObject and opening manually & using GetObject would seem to be time; so try using Excel's Wait method to pause a second or so before trying to open the file.

Comment: I added a 20 second wait - should be more than long enough since the plan opens in about 4. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to automatically open MSP files from Excel, to check if the application is already open or not

```
Function GetX(Str As String) As Object
    Dim app As Object
    On Error Resume Next

    Set app = GetObject(, Str)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set app = CreateObject(Str)
        app.Visible = False
        app.Clear
    End If

    Set GetX = app
End Function
```

then call function in module

```
Set ProjApp = GetX("MSProject.Application")
projapp.FileOpenEx Name:="<>\Name of my project", ReadOnly:=False
Set prj = Projects("Name of my project")
```